# AutoFilter Excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Estou com um problema, ao tentar fazer um autofilter no vba ele está tentando filtrar os valores que escolhi porem acaba não filtrando valor, procurei muito e não achei explicação. 
O código é o seguinte:

```
Dim nomeArquivo As String
        Dim gd As Integer
        nomeArquivo = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
        gd = CInt(nomeArquivo)
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$C$989088").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>" & gd
```

As condições são as seguintes o nome do arquivo no caso é 1102 e na coluna do filtro tinha a seguinte formula `=left(c7;4)` que retornava diversos valores sendo alguns deles 1102 então achei que o problema era a formula valorizei e tentei o codigo acima utilizando texto, depois tentei utilizando numeros e não obtive resultado, o que está errado ? por que continuo não filtrando nada?

Comment: Os valores são exatamente iguais a 1102? Ou somente contém este valor? E poderia [adicionar alguns valores diferentes da coluna C](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)? com o resultado esperado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porque o Excel está interpretando o valor em `Criteria1` como um **número** e os valores da coluna **`C`** como **texto**.

Tente alterar a fórmula da coluna `C` para `=VALUE(LEFT(C7, 4))` ou caso seja o Excel em português `VALOR(ESQUERDA(C7; 4))` e em seguida o seu código anterior (sem a necessidade dessa variável `integer`):

```
Dim nomeArquivo As String
nomeArquivo = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$C$989088").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>" & nomeArquivo
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda mas ainda está dando no mesmo... Não sei mais o que fazer com esse arquivo... Continua filtrando nada

Comment: Consegue disponibilizar um de exemplo pra download?

Comment: Cara, tava criando uma pra te enviar e percebi que ele ta filtrando o valor, mas não aparece na minha lista de filtros... então ta funcionando só não ta aparecendo na minha lista. Brigado pelo ajuda...

Comment: Você diz quando abre a lista ele não aparece marcado? Não entendi. De qualquer maneira, que bom que resolveu.